# Dotnet core web project in Raspberry Pi

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-server

I have installed dotnet core on my Raspberry PI running Ubuntu Server 16.04 as per https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/RaspberryPi/samples/ARMInstructions.md

I create and publish dotnet core project on Linux Mint 18 running dotnet core version 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177. (Also modifying runtimeconfig.json file to update the version to 1.2.0-beta-001206-00).
I then copy the published application into the Raspberry pi and run the dll.

For console application it works fine.

But when I repeat the steps for a web project and run it I get below error

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.CreateFileWatcher(String
>   root)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.Initialize(IHostingEnvironment
>   hostingEnvironment, String applicationName, String contentRootPath,
>   WebHostOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildHostingServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
>   WebApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   /home/Development/aspCoreDemo3/Program.cs:line 14 Aborted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the changes you need to make in the project.json.
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9168

Comment: The implementation done using VS 2017 as in the link worked. But if the project.json is modified as specified in the link for dotnet (version 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177) the on "dotnet restore" we get below error :
Errors in /../project.json
    Unable to resolve 'Machine.Core (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
    Unable to resolve 'Machine (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
Working on fixing it.